# How to stop .NET Core from mutilating file URIs

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uri

The [*Uri*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) constructor seems to be doing a lot of additional work when handling `file:` URIs, sometimes unfortunately to one's disadvantage. For example, `file:///a%A4b` is interpreted as `file:///a%A4b/a%A4b` via *AbsoluteUri* (and `file://%2Fa%A4b/a%A4b` in `ToString()` for some reason), and so is apparently every file URI that does not start with a drive letter and contains non-ASCII (even percent-encoded) characters.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour of `file:` URIs? It seems it has to be done globally, since I tried using different parameters in the constructor and it didn't work as well. I am fine with disabling any sort of special handling of `file:` URIs, since even (valid to my knowledge) URIs like `file:a` throw an exception due to that.

The issue seems to only crop up only in .NET Core up to 3.1. In .NET Framework or .NET 5, `new Uri("file:///a%A4b")` works as expected. Is there a way to get around this issue without upgrading or switching to .NET Framework?

Comment: Hmm, seems to be specific to my environment then, for some reason. I was running it on .NET Core 2.2 so it might be a bug there.

Comment: @mjwills It seems to affect all versions of .NET Core, so this question is now .NET Core-specific. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Did upgrading to .NET 5 help @IS4?

Comment: @mjwills I haven't tried yet, but I am confident it would. Still I'd prefer a different solution at the moment.

Comment: Alas there isn't likely to be a different solution, since it is a known issue that wasn't fixed until v5.

Comment: @mjwills True, but .NET also allows to add custom handlers for different URI schemes, as far as I remember. Perhaps one could *remove* one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in .NET Core prior to .NET 5. You will need to update to .NET 5.

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1031
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/36429
- https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/19965